# Bixby - How can I pass the whole $user object to method

Tags: bixby

I might need to use few attributes from $user in my javascript action file
How do I pass the whole object to my javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to pass the `$user` object into your Action Javascript.

However, most of the properties in the `$user` object are also available in the `$vivContext` object which can be passed into an Action Javascript.

To see how to pass `$vivContext` into your Action Javascript, I would recommend going through the [User Context sample capsule](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/user-context) available in the documentation